# How to setup LVM cache on ubuntu 14.10 server

Tags: server, system-installation, ssd, lvm

building a server machine for my personal server (media + application (docker))
I have two 2tb hdd(1 sata 2 old and 1 sata3) along with a samsung 120 gb ssd. I can format one of hdd but not both (atleast simultaneously have around 1.2tb data). I am looking for different setup options like (lvm) different caches like (cache fasthcache and lvmcache). Can someone please advice me what configuration would be ideal for me. I am looking for running a little app server for my hostel for a hostel wiki kind of thing at the same time I want to stream hd movies to my laptop (same wireless network).

Answer (score 0):

LVM Cache should be the best deal at this moment, it has incorporate all the underlying functionality. I wrote a passage about that to list down the procedures to setup LVM Cache.

https://www.jimmysyss.com/build-my-fusion-drive-with-lvm-cache/

The idea is sparing around 10-20GB for LVM Cache, several MB for the Cache Meta and configure "Write-back" mode for performance.